# AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'Constant'

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory

folks!

I'm using Google Colab to study a little more about Data Science. When I try to generate a chart using Plotly Express, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'Constant'
```

The chart I'm trying to generate is:

```
sample  = df.rename(columns={"location":"Location","num_sequences_total":"Number of Case"})
fig = px.treemap(sample, path=[px.Constant('Number of Case'),'Location'], values='Number of Case',
                   hover_data=['Location'])
fig.show()
```

The libraries I imported were:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas_profiling
import plotly.express as px
```

I tried to upgrade Plotly using `! pip install --upgrade plotly` but it did not work as well.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: Which plotly version do you have installed?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? `path=[px.Constant('Number of Case'),'Location']` px.Constant doesn't exits and don't comprehend why you would define path in this way.  update question to provide `sample.head(10)` in a text format (not an image!!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since you didn't give that much other information, two ideas:

1. Upgrade PIP (pip itself, not plotly) and reinstall plotly: `$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. You could try a submodule import: `from plotly import express as px` (untested)